# Unit Test using AutoFixture to guarantee an an entry in the returned list of objects

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, xunit.net, autofixture

I am writing a unit test that verifies that a controller method returns a list of objects. My Unit test is written using xUnit and AutoFixture, and code looks like the following:

```
// Arrange
var mockEmployeeRepo = new Mock<IEmployeeRepository>();
var employeeAccountsReturn = new Fixture().Create<List<Contracts.EmployeeAccount>>();
mockEmployeeRepo.Setup(employeeRepo => employeeRepo.GetEmployeeAccountsByEmployeeAccountId(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .Returns(employeeAccountsReturn);
var employeeAccountController = new EmployeeAccountController(mockEmployeeRepo.Object);

// Act
var result = employeeAccountController.GetEmployeeAccounts(1);

// Assert
Assert.Equal(employeeAccountsReturn, result);
```

I received feedback on this code asking if this Unit Test is deterministic whether or not creating via Fixture guarantee an entry in the list. Does the above apply to my Unit Test code? How can I use Fixture to guarantee an entry in the list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this test wouldn't be deterministic given you are using AutoFixture to generate a random list of EmployeeAccount objects. You'd be relying on AutoFixture to generate the same list on each run which I'm sure isn't the case.

If you are truly writing a unit test here, I'd ask you what does this controller method do? How much business logic is contained in the controller itself? If `GetEmployeeAccounts` merely calls the repository and returns that result then I think you're on the right track. You may also want to test that errors are handled correctly and the controller returns a meaningful error status.

Answer (score 0):

Is the test deterministic as written? That depends on how you interpret 'deterministic'. Usually, when you run a unit test suite, the test runner produces various statistics about the test run, such as when it was executed, how long it took, and so on. Viewed on that level, no test suites are ever deterministic.

If, on the other hand, you refer to determinism related to tests [as Martin Fowler discusses it](https://martinfowler.com/articles/nonDeterminism.html), the above test *may* be 'deterministic enough'. This, ultimately, depends on the intended implementation of the SUT.

AutoFixture, while creating random values, is designed with the intent that it should produce test cases that all fall within the same **Equivalence Class**. In this specific case, it never produces empty lists, but if you want to make that explicit in your test, you can always add a [Guard Assertion](http://xunitpatterns.com/Guard%20Assertion.html):

```
var employeeAccountsReturn = new Fixture().CreateMany<Contracts.EmployeeAccount>();
// Guard Assertion:
Assert.NotEmpty(employeeAccountsReturn);
mockEmployeeRepo
    .Setup(employeeRepo => employeeRepo.GetEmployeeAccountsByEmployeeAccountId(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .Returns(employeeAccountsReturn);
```

You can also make it more explicit that you're creating a collection by using the `CreateMany` method:

```
var employeeAccountsReturn = new Fixture().CreateMany<Contracts.EmployeeAccount>();
```

In this specific case, would it make a difference if the collection was empty? Wouldn't the test still pass? Shouldn't it?

Comment: Or you can create list manually with elements generate by AutoFixture ;)